# how to implement audio visualizer to exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, visualizer

I am working on a radio app . I used exoplayer as player on my project and I want to add audio visualizer on my playeractivity . but I couldn't find any tutorial or sample for it . I just made a customeRenderfactory and add it to my player . But I don't know what should I do more ? any help or suggestion ? I should mention my player work fine right now and I just need to find a solution to add visualizer to it .
RenderFactory class :

```
public class RenderFactory extends DefaultRenderersFactory {
private TeeAudioProcessor.AudioBufferSink listener;
private AudioProcessor[] aMProcessors;
private TeeAudioProcessor teeAudioProcessor;
private AudioRendererEventListener eventListener;

public RenderFactory(Context context, TeeAudioProcessor.AudioBufferSink myListener) {
    super(context);
    this.listener = myListener;
    teeAudioProcessor = new TeeAudioProcessor(this.listener);
}

@Override
protected void buildAudioRenderers(Context context, int extensionRendererMode, MediaCodecSelector mediaCodecSelector, @Nullable DrmSessionManager<FrameworkMediaCrypto> drmSessionManager, boolean playClearSamplesWithoutKeys, boolean enableDecoderFallback, AudioProcessor[] audioProcessors, Handler eventHandler, AudioRendererEventListener eventListener, ArrayList<Renderer> out) {

    aMProcessors = new AudioProcessor[]{teeAudioProcessor};
    super.buildAudioRenderers(context, extensionRendererMode, mediaCodecSelector, drmSessionManager, playClearSamplesWithoutKeys, enableDecoderFallback, aMProcessors, eventHandler, eventListener, out);
 }
}
```

in my playerActivity I added this code and set renderfactory to my player but nothing happened .

```
   RenderFactory renderFactory = new RenderFactory(this, new TeeAudioProcessor.AudioBufferSink() {
        @Override
        public void flush(int sampleRateHz, int channelCount, int encoding) {
            // what should I add here?
        }

        @Override
        public void handleBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
            // what should I add here?
        }
    });
```

I tried to followed this tutorial but I wasn't successful.

[tutorial](https://medium.com/@subasharyc/easy-visualizer-with-exoplayer-b310e73f677f)

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer your question:

```
@Override
public void flush(int sampleRateHz, int channelCount, int encoding) {
     // you dont have to do anything here
}

@Override
public void handleBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    // This will give you the bytes from the sound that is going to be played
    // here you apply FFT so the audio move to the frequency domain instead of time based
}
```

You can learn more about FFT [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)

FFT is a well known algorithm, so you may find it implemented on plenty os sites. You can use this [library](https://github.com/paramsen/noise) if yout want, but there is standalone codes around.

Once you have the FFT array, you can draw the values in a view.

You can use this guy's code as an example: https://github.com/dzolnai/ExoVisualizer

There's also a blog post he made about it: https://www.egeniq.com/blog/alternative-android-visualizer ([web archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20221004233851/https://www.egeniq.com/blog/alternative-android-visualizer))